# Hostname and IP address modification of 'k8s-master' in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is it mandatory to set hostname 'k8s-master' for master node in kubernetes?
Can we change IP address of the master node and child node after successful installation of kubernetes?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338) might help with changing the master node IP afterwards.

Comment: Also, while this isn't exactly what you asked, it is almost always a good idea to have a level of abstraction away from your master unless you are 100% certain your cluster will be single-master its whole life. That can be a DNS CNAME, `haproxy`, `ELB/NLB` etc, and _that_ is the name you would want to bake into your x.509, as well as `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` (et al) for when it is addressed from within the cluster

Answer (score 0):

In general, master node name composed from hostname of the machine where you bootstrap Kubernetes cluster, moreover master node name can be changed via building cluster procedure through kubeadm install tool:

`kubeadm init --node-name`.

Solution provided by [@valerius257](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-460935394) for Kubernetes master node IP replacement in a comment from @char works pretty fine, that was already checked in my environment. Answer retains for any further contributors research.